# How it is possible to connect with uniswap smart contract with uniswap sdk pakage without giving private key

Tags: javascript, node.js, blockchain, web3js, ethers.js

I am developing the decentralized application of assy indexes where we swap tokens using uniswap sdk. To complete the transaction I need to connect the account with uniswap smart contract. To connect with uniswap it requires a signer and signer connect the wallet with the private key.

You can see the steps below.

```
    provider = ethers.getDefaultProvider('rinkeby', {
      infura: 'https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/38a3d4450c784956877a1bd2fe75c406'
    })
    console.log('provider', provider)

    const signer = new ethers.Wallet(privateKey)
    console.log('signer', signer)

    const account = signer.connect(provider)
    console.log('account', account)

    const uniswap = new ethers.Contract(
      '0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D',
      uniswapAbi,
      **account**
    )
    console.log('Uniswap', uniswap)

    const to = this.accountAddress
```